# Discord.JS a bot that will saysomething in a specific channel upon comand

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I am newer to coding with js but have done a lot with other languages. I decided I want to make a discord bot, I learned some basic js and got started. After some time I was able to make a PingBot( type "!ping" it reply's "pong") Now I have tried making about that does something similar where you type "!word (#channel-name)" and it send a set message in #channel-name. I thought I had it but am now getting "Parsing error: Unexpected token ) (Fatal)" on line "26:2" (the last line of code). I could have completely messed up the code but I am not sure if I did.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!say")) {
        if (message.mentions.channels.size == 0) {
            message.reply("please type a channel of choise first.");
        }
        else {
            let targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();

            const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2);
            let saytext = args.join(" ");
            targetChannel.send(saytext);
            message.delete();
        }
    }
});
```

It won't even let me continue without fixing the problem and has left me confused about what I have done wrong.

Comment: Your if statement doesn't have a closing curly brace. Above the last line add a `}`

Answer (score -1):

A closing brace is missing.
Try :

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("!say")) {
        if (message.mentions.channels.size == 0) {
            message.reply("please type a channel of choise first.");
        }
        else {
            let targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();

            const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2);
            let saytext = args.join(" ");
            targetChannel.send(saytext);
            message.delete();
        }
    }
});
```